# WebRTC cannot show a video from peer

Tags: javascript, angular, video-streaming, webrtc

I've tried to implement code from this [sample](https://github.com/webrtc/samples/tree/gh-pages/src/content/peerconnection/pc1) in my app but something went wrong. The problem is my second peer, doesen't play the stream on `<video>`

The short description of algorithm is this: 
The "host" peer gets stream from camera and showing it on self `<video>`, then create connection with second peer and sending to him a stream. The second peer receive the stream and show on his `<video>`

The problem is my second peer receive stream, but couldn't play it on . Why? I don't know.

Here there are some code from my app:

**Host Peer init:**

```
var configuration ={
  'iceServers': [
    {
      "urls": "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
      "username": "xxxxxx@gmail.com",
      "credential": "xxxxx"
    }
  ],RTCIceTransportPolicy:'all'
};

var offerOptions = { offerToReceiveVideo: 1, offerToReceiveAudio: 1 };
const peer = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);
peer.addStream(this.stream);
peer.createOffer(
      (desc)=>{
        console.log("host createOffer ", desc)
        peer.setLocalDescription(desc).then(
          (data)=>{
            console.log("host setLocalDesc succes")
            this.sendInvitation(desc, user)
        },(error)=>{
            console.log("host setLocalDesc error")
        });

      },(error)=>{
        console.log("host createOffer error",error)
      },
      offerOptions
    );
```

> this.sendInvitation(desc,user) sends via websockets the desc object to
>   "second" peer

**Host code for accepting new peer**

```
client.setRemoteDescription(clientAnswer).then(
  (data) => console.log("host setRemote succes"),
  (error) => console.log("host setRemote succes")
)

client.onicecandidate = function(e){
  console.log("try to addIceCandidate",e);
  client.addIceCandidate(e.candidate).then(
    (data)=>console.log("host addIceCandidate succes"),
    (error)=>console.log("host addIceCandidate error")
  );
};

client.oniceconnectionstatechange = function(e){
  console.log("host connectionChange", e)
};
```

**Client, "second" peer init**

```
var configuration ={
  'iceServers': [
    {
      "urls": "turn:numb.viagenie.ca",
      "username": "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      "credential": "xxxxx"
    }
  ],RTCIceTransportPolicy:'all'
};

this.peerClient = new RTCPeerConnection(configuration);

this.peerClient.onaddstream = (ev)=>{
  this.isConnected = true;
  console.log("client onAddStream ", ev);

  if (this.video.nativeElement.srcObject !== ev) {

    var streams = this.peerClient.getRemoteStreams();

    console.log(this.peerClient.getLocalStreams())
    console.log(this.peerClient.getRemoteStreams())
    console.log(streams[0].getTracks())
    console.log(ev.stream)

    this.video.nativeElement.srcObject = ev.stream;
    this.stream = ev.stream;
  }

  this.calculateChatHeight();
};
```

**And the function in "client"/"second" peer side - the join button**

```
this.peerClient.setRemoteDescription(peerOffer).then(
        (data) => console.log("client setRemote succes",data),
        (error) => console.log("client setRemote error",error)
      )

      this.peerClient.createAnswer().then(
        (desc)=>{

          this.peerClient.setLocalDescription(desc).then(
            (data) => console.log("client setLocal succes", data),
            (error) => console.log("client setLocal error", error)
          );

          this.answer = desc;

          this.sendPeerAnswer();

        },(error) => console.log("client createAnswer error", error)
      )

      this.peerClient.onicecandidate = (e)=>{
        this.peerClient.addIceCandidate(e.candidate).then(
          (data)=>console.log("client addIceCandidate succes", data),
          (error)=>console.log("client addIceCandidate error", error)
        )
      };
```

Now, the code looks good, but the video is not showing on client

Please have a look on this screen from client console - everything looks nice.

[image]

Do You have any idea what's wrong? Please, help

> EDIT I realised that the bug is in IceConnection. The correct way for
>   IceConnection is  ICE state:new => checking => connected => completed
>   But in my example is stopping at CHECKING. Do You know why?

Comment: Ice transport policy should be added as iceTransportPolicy instead of RTCIceTransportPolicy, as iceTransportPolicy accepts values from RTCIceTransportPolicy enum. Please check what candidate you received in onicecandidate callback is in the correct format or not. Add the received candidate details if you not sure if the value you received is correct or not.

Comment: Have you investigated from the log "addIceCandidate error TypeError: Candidate missing values for both sdpMid and sdpMLineIndex" Stopping at checking could be due to so many things... First of all, it might not even be your application. It could be the device, browser, and/or network. My advice would be to log the SDP and ICE candidates as well as the connection state via `oniceconnectionstatechange`

Comment: Maybe [this](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/webrtc-web/tree/master/step-05) is a better example? I got this example up and running in no time. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: @HermanFransen The main bug in my app is I have big mess in this whole icecandidates, offers and answers. All i had to do, was call addIceCandidates, and setDescriptions in right order, and right states. Using "then" on promises is also important. But thanks for example, it's good to have many sources of examples while doing something in webrtc :D